# Why is my AngularJS binding not always updating properly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm creating a simple image uploading page that works with AWS S3 using [Danial Farid's ng-file-upload plugin](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). It features a simple button to upload a new image and a list of images. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in product.images">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="{{ image }}" target="_blank">
          <img ng-src="{{ image }}" alt="image">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-image-upload" 
            ngf-select 
            ngf-change="upload($files)"
            ngf-accept="'image/*'"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On my controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {

    var aws_policy, aws_policy_signature;

    if (files && files.length) {
        $http
            .get(API_URL+'/helper/aws_policy')
            .then(function(data) {
                aws_policy = data.data.policy;
                aws_policy_signature = data.data.signature;
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    var key = generate_aws_key() + '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();
                    var base_url = 'https://.../';

                    Upload
                    .upload({ ... })
                    .success(function( data, status, headers, config ) {

                        console.log($scope.product);
                        $scope.product.images.push( base_url + key );
                        console.log($scope.product);

                    });
                }
            });
    }
};
```

The file is being uploaded properly (I get a nice `204 Success` from AWS) and the two `console.log($scope.product)`'s get called showing the appropriate results (the second one features the item on the `images` array).

Here's the thing. This baby works perfectly on my development machine, but *sometimes* on the staging or production servers, the list of images is not being updated when `$scope.product.images` is. By sometimes, I mean that it does it 1/3rd of the times.

**Summarizing**

*Sometimes*, only on my production server, the DOM is not updated when `$scope.product.images` is updated inside AngularJS digest.

My programming experience taught me that *sometimes* is not an acceptable concept in this type of matters and that it must be related to something that *always* happens when this problem arises, but I debugged extensively and failed to find the real cause. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping you success code in $timeout()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely caused by [looping within asynchronous callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?lq=1):

You have to freeze the value of `i`:

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {

    var aws_policy, aws_policy_signature;

    function upload(index) {
        var file = files[index];
        var key = generate_aws_key() + '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();
        var base_url = 'https://.../';

        Upload
        .upload({ ... })
        .success(function( data, status, headers, config ) {

            console.log($scope.product);
            $scope.product.images.push( base_url + key );
            console.log($scope.product);

        });
    }

    if (files && files.length) {
        $http
            .get(API_URL+'/helper/aws_policy')
            .then(function(data) {
                aws_policy = data.data.policy;
                aws_policy_signature = data.data.signature;
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    upload(i);
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, this is new to me. It's theoretically the same code I wrote!